# Dynamically link to child page WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I'm using subpages on a WP site as follows;

Products (Parent Page)
-Office (Subpage 1)
--Office Gallery (Child of Subpage 1)
-School (Subpage 2)
--School Gallery (Child of Subpage 2)
....etc

How can I create a link on each subpage to its child page using just one template in my theme? I need to be able to give this link a css class name. In other words I need to have the code in my page template look something like:

> `<a class="gallery-button" href="RETURN LINK TO CHILD PAGE OF CURRENT PAGE"></a>`

or something like that......

I tried using wp_list_pages for a child page from the WordPress Codex but this returns a list and I really need just the permalink to the child page.

Is this easy? Impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to query posts to get the first child of the post in question;

```
<?php
    if ($children = get_children('post_type=page&numberposts=1')) {
        $first_child = $children[0];
        $first_child_permalink = get_permalink($first_child->ID);
        echo '<a class="gallery-button" href="' . $first_child_permalink . '">Link Text</a>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a revision of TheDeadMac's code I ended with that works in WP 3.9:

```
$children = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
$first_child = $children[0];
$first_child_permalink = get_permalink($first_child->ID);
echo '<a href="' . $first_child_permalink . '">Link Text</a>';
```